# Query is not working?

Tags: database, module, custom, column, modal-popup

/*I need those questions whose status is 1 but its not working*/

```
 <?php $i=1;
    //$coll=$collection->getSelect()->where("`main_table`.`status`= 1");
    //$collection->load(true); // To dump the sql as text again and its working fine
    
     foreach ($collection->getSelect()->where("`main_table`.`status`= 1") as $item) {?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="requirement">Question :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Question" name="question<?=$i?>" 
            value="<?= $item->getQuestion();?>">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="requirement">Answer :</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="requirement" name="answer<?=$i?>">
            </textarea>
     
       <?php $i++;}
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better add a status filter for collection

```
public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
        
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it is working I applied addtofilter inside the loop and it is working

Comment: Could you please help for how to send this form data in the owner's email?

Comment: https://store.magenest.com/blog/how-to-send-email-in-magento-2/ follow this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Just inject your CollectionFactory or model Factory dependency in your constructor like the following -

```
{
   protected $collection;

   public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResuorceModel\YOUR_ReourceModelName\CollectionFactory $collection
   ){
      $this->collection = $collection;
   }

   public function getCollection()
   {
      return $this->collection->create()->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
   }
}
```